# How to delete parts of a textual vector using gsub and regular expressions

Tags: r, regex, replace, gsub, regex-lookarounds

I have a list in which each element contains a vector of textual data. 
In essence, I would like the code to delete text that follows after a regular expression: the second "." in the respective vector.

I believe the gsub-function is a good way to go about this if used in connection with regular expressions. I have tried to formulate the pattern to be detected using a regular expression (see below).

Data:

```
v<-c("M. le président. La parole est à M. Emile Vernaudon.",
       "M.Gabriel Xaaperei. Monsieur le ministre",
       "M. Raymond Fornir, rapporteur. La commission")
```

Code:

`Subbed<-gsub("[^((?<=^M. *))]", "X", v)`

The code returns the following:

```
[1] "M. XX XXXXXXXXX. XX XXXXXX XXX. M. XXXXX XXXXXXXXX."
[2] "M. XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX. MXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXX XXX"    
[3] "M. XXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX. XX XXXXXXXXXX"
```

Not only does the code take all the "M."s into account, but there is also an "M" in the second row although it is not followed by a ".".
My hunch is that in gsub regular expressions seem to work differently - the "M." in my code might be read by R as "M|." Also, the ^ after the Lookaround doesn't seem to work as an anchor but simply as an additional punctuation character.

The desired outcome is as follows:

```
[1] "M. le président."
[2] "M. Gabriel Xaaperei."
[3] "M. Raymond Fornir, rapporteur."
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Regex only work on strings, not other data types like vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) sub** Match the beginning of string (^) and then capture M. .  Next match spaces if any and then capture everything up to the next dot.  Finally match everything else.  Replace that with the first capture (\1), a space and the second capture (\2).

Note that we use `sub` rather than `gsub` since there is just one overall match per component.  Also, it puts a space after the M. even if it did not already have one.

```
sub("^(M\\.) *([^.]+\\.).*", "\\1 \\2", v)
```

giving:

```
[1] "M. le président."               "M. Gabriel Xaaperei."          
[3] "M. Raymond Fornir, rapporteur."
```

**2) read.table** This solution does not use any regular expressions.  We read in `v` using dot separated fields and then assemble them back together using `sprintf`.

```
with(read.table(text = v, sep = ".", fill = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE), 
  sprintf("%s. %s.", V1, V2))
```

giving:

```
[1] "M. le président."               "M. Gabriel Xaaperei."          
[3] "M. Raymond Fornir, rapporteur."
```

**3) paste/trimws/sub** This uses several functions and only one regex which is relatively simple.  We take everything from the 3rd character onwards, replace the first dot and everything after it with a dot, trim whitespace in case any is left and paste M. onto the beginning.

```
paste("M.", trimws(sub("\\..*", ".", substring(v, 3))))
```

giving:

```
[1] "M. le président."               "M. Gabriel Xaaperei."          
[3] "M. Raymond Fornir, rapporteur."
```

Add

Answer (score 2):

```
    gsub("^([^.]*.[^.]*).*", "\\1.", v)

[1] "M. le président."               "M.Gabriel Xaaperei."           
[3] "M. Raymond Fornir, rapporteur."
```

Answer (score 1):

You placed your regular expression within square brackets, which R interprets as a group, and then indeed treats everything in that group as "OR". You also preceded that with ^, which makes R treat it as "NOT", so it basically looks for anything but the characters in your search term.
Furthermore, you didn't escape your periods. Here's the regex as it should be:

```
gsub("^(M\\..*?\\.).*","\\1",v)
[1] "M. le président."               "M.Gabriel Xaaperei."           
[3] "M. Raymond Fornir, rapporteur."
```

This looks for `M.` (the period is escaped), followed by anything (unescaped .) for an undetermined number of times (`*`) which is followed by a second (escaped) period (the `?` is to make sure it's ungreedy, so it doesn't look for the last period, only the next one).

It them returns everything up to there (`\\1`), and discards the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step explanation. I haven't come across the (\\1) before. Out of curiosity: how does it work? What does it refer to in the "pattern"-part of the gsub-function? If I change it to (\\2), all is discarded and there is no output.

Comment: \\1 refers to the contents of the parenthesis. If you have multiple parenthetical expressions, you can refer to them using \\n. (see, e.g., the first solution in the accepted answer)